# Does -rpath and $LD_LIBRAY_PATH has same functionality?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, ubuntu-18.04

The book [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/%7Ehungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) contains:

> The system searches only /lib and /usr/lib, by default. If a shared library that is linked into your program is installed outside those directories, it will not be found, and the system will refuse to run the program.

> One solution to this problem is to use the -Wl, -rpath option when linking the program. Another solution to this problem is to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable when running the program.

So from information above, I assume adding path to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` **is equivalent to** passing argument to linker when compiling something like `-Wl,-rpath,SOME_PATH` until I hit this problem:

I am trying to generate a **shared library** and this shared library depends on some .so files somewhere at my system. Here's the command for compilation:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libA.so -o libA.so SRC.cpp -L PATH_A -I PATH_B  -Wl,-rpath,PATH_C:PATH_D:PATH_E -la -lb -lc
```

After I compile, I use `ldd` to check if there's any dependency issue and something unexpected to me happens:

Some of dependency are found and some of them are not (`libA.so => not found`), however all the paths it needs (`PATH_C PATH_DPATH_E`) have been passed to argument `-Wl,-rpath`.

So it seems `-Wl,-rpath` does not work for this case **, the only solution to make it work**  **is to add the path to `libA.so` to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH** and `ldd` returns that all the dependency are found.

I would like to know why `-Wl,-rpath` fails in, **what's the difference between adding the path to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and passing an argument to `-Wl,-rpath`**?

Comment: You've rearranged your _actual_ problem _too much_, to the point where it's impossible to understand what binary you are running `ldd` on, and which library is not found. Is it `liba.so` or `libA.so` that is giving you trouble? Please show your _actual_ link command, and _actual_ `ldd` output.